# CSS3 fallback for older browsers

Tags: css, gradient, fallback

I have made a circle using CSS3, trouble is in older browsers (ie7 etc) the circle appears as a square.

I know I could use a background image as a backup, but doesnt this defeat the point of using code?

If i was to put  background-image in, where would it go in the CSS?

```
.ButtonB:hover, .ButtonB.hover {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(
        center top,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 0%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, .1) 100%
    );/* FF3.6 */
    background: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        center bottom,
        center top,
        from(rgba(255, 255, 255, .1)),
        to(rgba(255, 255, 255, .2))
    );/* Saf4+, Chrome */
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#33FFFFFF', EndColorStr='#19FFFFFF'); /* IE6,IE7 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#33FFFFFF', EndColorStr='#19FFFFFF')"; /* IE8 */
}
```

Comment: All that code for a little circle...why not just use the image for all browsers? All that code may need changing in the future because you are using browser specific tags. However `.ButtonB:hover,  ButtonB.hover { background: url('yourpathtoimage'); }` job done, all browsers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the following will provide better support for a variety of browsers and will fallback to a solid colour when gradients are not supported, you could replace this solid colour with an image.

```
background: #0A284B;  /* for images use #0A284B url(image.jpg)*/
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0A284B), to(#135887));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#0A284B, #135887);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0A284B, #135887);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#0A284B, #135887);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#0A284B, #135887);
background: linear-gradient(#0A284B, #135887);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0A284B', endColorstr='#135887');
zoom: 1;
```

You will need to specify a `height` or `zoom: 1` to apply `hasLayout` to the element for this to work in IE.

Comment: thanks for this blowise, i'll go with this code. think i'll go for a background image as the square doesn't look so good.

Comment: Thanks. For me the trick was putting the single-color background first, before thie others.

Answer (score 2):

```
.ButtonB:hover, .ButtonB.hover {
    background: url('yourpathtoimage'); /* for old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(
        center top,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 0%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, .1) 100%
    );/* FF3.6 */
    ...
}
```

In this case if browser support `linear-gradient` it will override first line.

Answer (score 2):

You're using a whole load of CSS features that aren't supported in older browsers -- gradients, alpha channel transparency, may border radius too.

Short answer is that often the best answer is simply to leave it and let the really old browsers show it differently; it may not look as pretty as you intended, but if it's usable in IE7 then you've probably done enough already.

If you really do need to support these features in IE7 and other old browsers then you might want to look into [CSS3Pie](http://www.css3pie.com/), which provides a javascript-based fallback solution in IE for all of the features I can see you using here. Download the script and follow the instructions on the site for setting it up.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Just a pointer, CSS3 Pie can make a webpage very slow. Particularly pages with large a DOM

Comment: @Blowsie : do you mean it will make a webpage very slow ON OLD IE VERSIONS ONLY, or does it affect new IE versions / other browsers too ?

Comment: @AndreaLigios it uses feature detection so the overhead isn't huge on modern browsers but it can cripple IE.